# Image slider transition not cycling back properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I attempted to make a image slider that transition to a new image in a few second. However, for some reason it does not go back to the picture in the beginning and seems to try to awkwardly transition. Here the link to the rest of the code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YvPdNj

```
var i = 0; //title
var size = 0 //image
var fade = 4000;

function imgTransition() {
   var transit = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
   for(var i= 0; i < transit.length - 1; i++) {
       transit[size].style.opacity = 0;
   }
   if (size < transit.length - 1) {
      size++;
      transit[size].style.opacity = 1;
   }
   else {
      size = 0;
      transit[size].style.opacity = 1;
   }
   setInterval('imgTransition()', fade);
}

window.onload = function() {
   imgTransition();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few changes I made to your code:

First I made changes to your `global` variables as I added `imgind` for image index, `transit` for the image collection then I assign the `transit` and `size` variable in the `load` event so you don't have to assign them again and again in the code then I Commented the function `titleTransition()` call in the `load` event as it is not declared (which you might use later on) and also made the 1st image's `opacity` to 1 as it is to be displayed first and then called the `setInterval(imgTransition, fade);` instead of `imgTransition()` so that the set interval is sepearte of code and is not calling it self.

Here take a look at this modified snippet:

> **Snippet**

```js
var i = 0; //title
var imgind = 0;
var size = 0 //image
var time = 3000;
var fade = 4000;
var transit = null;


function imgTransition() {
  transit[imgind].style.opacity = 0; //hiding the indexed image
  imgind++; //incrementing the image index
  if (imgind >= size) //checking if the index is greater then or equals to size
    imgind = 0; //setting index to 1st image i.e 0.
  transit[imgind].style.opacity = 1; //displaying the next image     

}


window.onload = function() {
  transit = document.getElementsByTagName("img"); // get the collection of images
  size = transit.length; //get the size of images
  transit[imgind].style.opacity = 1; //to set the opacity of 1st image
  setInterval(imgTransition, fade);
  //titleTransition(); //undefined funciton


};
```

```css
img {
  transition: all .5s ease-in;
  left: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/68dd54ca-60cf-4ef7-898b-26d7cbe48ec7/10-dithering-opt.jpg" alt="Mountain View" width="500" height="377">
<img src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426" alt="Mountain View" width="500" height="377">
```